# xaml TextBlock to show text with partial bold font

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I will get a string from my database and set part of it (e.g. matched the keyword) to be bold. And then show it on a TextBlock.
E.g. "Hi, who is **Tom**? I need to find him."

I refer to this link:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb1f558c-a2dd-4977-85d7-8e0ce9631681/how-to-make-part-of-a-string-bold-in-c?forum=aspgettingstarted  to translate the matched word to be bold:

```
private string FormatString(string wholeString, string boldPart)
{
    return Regex.Replace(wholeString, boldPart, @"<b>$0</b>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Then I get this formatted new string "Hi, who is <b>Tom</b>? I need to find him."

But after I put it to a TextBlock's Text property, I just got some errors like below.
[image]

Comment: In order to set such a text dynamically, you have to access the Inlines property of the TextBlock.

Comment: Duplicate mark link goes to a solution which is a "static" solution, for a known text. But that is not a solution for multiple text (dynamic), get from a database, for example. When you have dynamic text, duplicate link will not have a solution for this. Look for my answer, it will solve your issue whit any text you'll set to `TextBlock` object.
So, this is not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split text in multiple `Run`s and use `FontWeight` for your bold text.

```xml
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Who is "/>
    <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="Tom"/>
    <Run Text="? I need to find him!"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Or

```
<TextBlock>Who is <Bold>Tom</Bold>? I need to find him!</TextBlock>
```

**Edited:**
To be able to add different format in a single `TextBlock` I think you maybe subscribe to `TargetUpdated` event of your `TextBlock` and add `Run` class for each string between `<b>` and `</b>`

Exemple for `TargetUpdated` event:

```cs
        private void MyText_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
        {
            string text = myText.Text;

            if (text.Contains("<b>") && text.Contains("</b>"))
            {
                int nrOfB = text.Split("<b>", StringSplitOptions.None).Length - 1;
                myText.Text = "";
                string textAfter ="";
                for (int i = 0; i < nrOfB; i++)
                {
                    int startIndex = text.IndexOf("<b>");
                    int endIndex = text.IndexOf("</b>");
                    string textBefore = text.Substring(0, startIndex);
                    string textBolded = text.Substring(startIndex + 3, endIndex - (startIndex + 3));
                    textAfter = text.Substring(endIndex + 4);
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Text Before: {textBefore},\nTextBolded: {textBolded},\nTextAfter: {textAfter}");
                    myText.Inlines.Add(new Run(textBefore));
                    myText.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run(textBolded)));
                    text = textAfter;
                }
                myText.Inlines.Add(new Run(textAfter));

            }
        }
```

and xaml control will be:

```xml
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="local:Test"> 
            <Setter Property="MyText" Value="{Binding MyTextVM, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

<TextBlock x:Name="myText" Text="{Binding ElementName=TestV, Path=MyText, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" TargetUpdated="MyText_TargetUpdated"/>
```

```
local:Test - my View,
TestV - Name for the view,
MyText - DependencyProperty of my custom TextBlock class,
MyTextVM - property from ViewModel
```

This string: `My Text is a <b>Bold</b> text. <b>Second</b> text bold is <b>Bolded</b> too.` will create this visual effect:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Clemens. After I posted answer I tough more about it, and this solution is quite hard coded. I don't think is a good idea. Now I'm testing something to care about `TargetUpdated` event, and to replace text of `Textblock` with multiple `Run`, depending on how many `<b>` are in text.

Comment: Ok, I've added the good solution, for dynamic string. Look in Edit.